# draw a custom drawable without any size in Android

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm trying to draw a drawable background with a path. But i getting to one point where i can't draw because i need the size of the object that will receive the background. Is there a function to find the size of the specific view that i will draw on ?

```
public class CustomDrawableEditText extends Drawable{
private Context context;
public CustomDrawableEditText(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(10, 0);
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, Y);
    path.lineTo(10,  Y);
    path.moveTo( X, 0);
    path.lineTo( X-10, 0);
    path.moveTo( X, 0);
    path.lineTo( X,  X);
    path.lineTo( X-10,  X);
    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

private int getY() {
    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    final float scale = res.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (res.getDimension(R.dimen.dim4) * scale + 0.5f);
}
@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the size of a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) you can invoke `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. Note that you might be interested in `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` as well.

Make sure these methods are called **after the layout process** of your view.

Comment: @Tsunaze I added another line.

Comment: the view in question appears through a layoutinflater after a click button. I think it's after the process of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `Drawable.getBounds()` or `Drawable.copyBounds(Rect rect)` methods.

These two methods should return the `View`'s bounds (when a `View`'s size changes, it calls (should call) the `Drawable.setBounds` method on each `Drawable` it has with the appropriate parameter values) in which the `View` wants your `Drawable` to be drawn. Your own custom-Drawable can then retrieve this value by calling `Drawable.getBounds()` or `Drawable.copyBounds(Rect rect)`.